# Error using file_get_contents() in PHP

Tags: php, file-get-contents

```
echo "Enter file path:";
$filePathV2C = fgets(STDIN);
$fileString=file_get_contents($filePathV2C);
print $fileString;
```

Input I provide is: `c:\phpFile\myfile.v2c`

but i get following error:

> Warning: file_get_contents(file://C:/php/myfile.v2c
>   ): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\php_CloudWSsample\Sample.php

Comment: Try without protocol `file://`

Comment: Tried but still can't get it to work. If i put the filename directly in the file_get_contents it works like file_get_contents("c:\php\myfile.v2c"); but with a variable name it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try by giving input as: "c:/phpFile/myfile.v2c"